# Can we import Data from Amazon S3 to an RDS SQL Server Database without integeration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I need to import data from an Amazon S3 bucket to an RDS SQL Server Database without the integration between Amazon RDS SQL Server and Amazon S3. Do we have any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To perform this use case, you can write a Lamdba function that uses the Amazon S3 API and a data base API in your programming language that can place data into the SQL Server Database. You would perform these tasks:

- Read the data from the Amazon S3 bucket.
- If the data is in a format like JSON, parse the data
- Open a connection to the database
- Run an INSERT SQL operation using the data you obtained from the S3 bucket.

You cannot perform this task with coding an app or Lambda function.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. The AWS [Schema Conversion Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/schema-conversion-tool) does not appear to offer an S3-to-MySQL solution, almost certainly because the shape of the data could be anything. This seems like a good scenario for a custom solution, and Lambda can give you some high parallelization for doing the job quickly.

Comment: If I had to solve this - this is how i would do it.